# Can Azure blob storage functions bind with multiple input?

Tags: python, azure, function

I want to use 2 blobs containers to trigger that azure function. Is there also a way to recognized which blob storage trigger the azure function? Please help. Thank you! Python

Answer (score 0):

> There are no plans to support multiple triggers per Function.

**Each function has only one trigger** but it can have multiple input bindings.

For your need, aving your blob uploads trigger an Event Grid event, and have an [Event Grid Triggered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=python) function which is fired for each blob uploaded.